# How to build 2 dependent (on each other) DLL's, while they aren't being compiled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I have two separate DLL's in Visual Studio.

`A` needs to use specific method from `B`

and also

`B` needs to use specific method from `A`

However, while I open the solutions separately, neither one compiles (saying `...are you missing an assembly reference`). Is including one project in another solution, the only way to solve that?

Comment: You have to separate common methods to another project and both projects have that reference. Is a better design and you avoid circle references.

Comment: Somewhat easy - build partial A that does not need B (make sure name is correct so it can be replaced with full A at the end), build B using A from previous step, build complete A. Now you have A and B with circular dependency...

Answer (score 3):

If you are in this situation, it means your architecture is not correct. Circular referencing is seriously not a good idea, it brings you in the world of DLL mess. It is not even possible and this is why you get he error.

I remember a situation back in 2002 where .NET was all new to us. The team came with the great solution of using reflection to get access to the objects of DLL B from A. At the end we had en inter-twined spagetti, no one could get their heads around.

Solution:
Think very well what code belongs together and how can you build proper "black boxes" which are independand functional pieces of code.

You might consider defining some interfaces to be used by both dll's. There is also a change you should not be having two dll's in the first place.

Comment: `If you are in this situation, it means your architecture is not correct` A typical, flat-footed, "you are doing it wrong" non-answer that ignores that sometimes there are cases where this is a solution. Either forced into this situation by an external dependency, or that some alternative is actually worse.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, you are right, , in some situations you cannot get arround using reflection. However the example above clearly states the person has control over both dll's.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid circular reference you need those methods that are needed from project A in project B and project B in project A to extract to another assembly and name the assembly for example "Shared".

Reflection can help you access these methods that you need but it's a bad practice and nobody will recommend you to go that way.